# UIModalPresentationPageSheet Gives different view in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, presentviewcontroller

`UIModalPresentationPageSheet` is not working in iOS8.

```
MyViewController *myViewController=[[MyViewController alloc] init];
myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code works just fine in iOS6 and iOS7. But with iOS8 it just gives a full screen view just like `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

How can I have iOS7-`UIModalPresentationPageSheet`-like view in iOS8? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an early beta bug. Make sure to open a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.